# Imperva WAF (Web application firewall) - No HTTP hits

Tags: networking, web-applications

We have run a script on a particular WEB application, we could see the alerts and violation for the respective server group.
But Couldn't see any HTTP hits for the same server group.

Could somebody help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to serverfault. I think if you can edit your post with a little bit more description you can probably help you better. For instance, more details about the firewall setup? what ports are open/blocked? what do you see in the log?

Comment: thank you for your response,
there is a team which is currently checking how much load the application can take.
so while they were testing, we could see the traffic but in our dashboard we couldn't see the http hits.